# Unable to throw error in angular js promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an as promise as :

```
try {    
   myPromise().then(function(){
       console.log("ok");
     }, function(err) { throw err; });
} catch(e) {
    console.log("error");
}
```

now my control goes to the `function(err)` and it throws the error but the error is not caught in `catch()`.

Comment: Try to log **console.log("err");** instead of throwing the error **throw err;**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because promises are asynchronous, flow control doesn't work the way you're thinking it will.  Your try...catch block is *outside* of the promise initialization code, and once it initializes the promise, it's done.  So the try...catch block is only handling promise initialization in the code above.  If the promise is rejected/errored (as you say it is doing in your code), the error function will fire within the error function closure only.

Consider a common error handler or you can refactor your try...catch block to be within the closure.

Here's the code with the common error handler:

```
try {    
   myPromise().then(function(){
       console.log("ok");
     }, function(err) { 
       errHandler(err); 
     });
} catch(e) {
    errHandler(e);
}


function errHandler(err) {
   console.log("error");
}
```

Comment: Outer `try/catch` is redundant

Comment: The outer try...catch will handle any errors in the `myPromise()` function that's returning the promise.  It may very well be worthless if there's nothing in that function that would throw an error.  It demonstrates the use of a refactored, common error handler, however.

Comment: But since it is returning a promise any error would get passed to the final promise catch..no?

Comment: I would think not.  Consider a function like this:
`function myPromise() {
   return null;
}`
If that's what the `myPromise()` function looks like, the second line of my sample will throw an error and be caught by the outer error handler before a promise is instantiated.  Highly unlikely, but you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

**1) Use Promise.catch:**

```ts
myPromise().then(function(){
       console.log("ok");
     }, function(err) { throw err; })
     .catch(function(err) { console.log("error"); });
```

**2) If you have transpiler use async/await:**

```ts
async function parentFunction() {
  try {
    await myPromise();
    console.log("ok");
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log("error");
  }
}
```